# Are there any Yiddish Peruishim on the Parsha?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, pentateuch-chumash, yiddish

Are there any Yiddish Perushim on the Parsha? I am aware of the Tzena U'Reana,the Chumash Beis Yehuda which is a Yiddish Translation of Rashi and of the Lubavitcher Rebbe's Sichos written in Yiddish who had some of his Sichos Recorded in Yiddish. Besides for that I am not aware of any others, despite the language of instruction/learning for many of the European Chachamim.

Comment: you just listed quite a lot in yiddish on parsha. Likkutei Sichois by itself is almost entirely yiddish (I think lamed beis is not) and is around 36 volumes.  Also there are the unedited sichois as well and farbrengens.

Comment: Yiddish was relatively popular at a time learning Tanakh relatively wasn't.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yiddish was however the language of study for many European Talmedei Chachamim

Answer (score 3):

[Der Yidishe Raidner](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/2240)

[Drashos in Yiddish](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/2233)